# Convert a byte[] pdf with multiple pages into a ceTe.DynamicPDF.Document

Tags: c#, dynamicpdf

Is there a way to convert a byte array pdf with multiple pages into a ceTe.DynamicPDF.Document object ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Document` instance, then use [MergeDocument](https://www.dynamicpdf.com/docs/dotnet/cete.dynamicpdf.merger.mergedocument.-ctor#Byte___Int32_Int32_MergeOptions_) passing your byte array.

Example [here](https://github.com/DynamicPDF/coresuite-dotnet-core-framework/blob/c191f64e552a0f03cf7bc4dd3844b4aa5f4c272b/coresuite-dotnet-core-console-cs/merger/MergePDFs.cs#L12).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a MergeDocument instead of a Document. A PdfDocument can be created from a byte array. It retains all the pages of the PDF. The PdfDocument can be appended to a mergeDocument.

```
PdfDocument myPdfDoc = new PdfDocument(myByteArray);
myMergeDoc.Append(myPdfDoc);
```

If you specifically need a ceTe.DynamicPDF.Document you can make a MergeDocument, add the PdfDocument to it, then iterate through the pages in the MergeDocument and save them to a Document. Admittedly, that is a messy solution.

```
foreach (Page page in myMergeDoc.Pages)
{
    myDocument.Pages.Add(page);
}
```